# Remove dependency from pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods, gdata

How do I remove dependency from a pod?

I have a podfile with

```
pod 'GData'
```

which seems to be broken, because it generates 163 duplicate symbols errors. I think I know what it is. While installing this can be observed:

```
Installing GTMHTTPFetcher (1.141)
Installing gtm-http-fetcher (1.0.141)

[!] GTMHTTPFetcher has been deprecated in favor of gtm-http-fetcher
```

One of these is not needed. So to remove it I try to modify podfile to use custom, local podspec file:

```
podspec :path => '~/GData.podspec.json'
```

In which podspec file I copy all of original JSON podspec contents without GTMHTTPFetcher, GData DOES not install. It even happens if I just copy original contentes and don't change anything at all. All dependencies are installed, but GData itself is not. I think that I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is proper podfile syntax for using custom podspec (in a JSON format):

```
pod 'pod_name_goes_here', :podspec => 'path/to/your/file.podspec.json'
```

And to delete dependency, simply remove an entry from 'dependencies', for example change

```
"dependencies": {
  "GTMHTTPFetcher": [
  ],
  "gtm-oauth2": [
  ]        
}
```

to

```
"dependencies": {
  "gtm-oauth2": [
  ]        
}
```

And now pod will be installed without "GTMHTTPFetcher".