# How to remove dependency from Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have installed Google tag manager through Cocoapods using "pod 'GoogleTagManager', '~> 5.0'". This has dependencies like "GoogleAnalytics (3.17.0)" and "GoogleUtilities (1.3.2)".

There is GoogleAnalytics library already included in my project and Can't delete this library due to some problems. So what i want to do is either

1. Exclude this dependency (GoogleAnalytics) while "pod install"

or

2. Remove this dependency after "pod install"

whichever is possible.

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595295/remove-dependency-from-pod), but I am not aware of **custom, local podspec file**. Any help in this regard is much appreciable. Thank you.

Comment: Removing the line `pod GoogleAnalytics` and `pod install` should do the job normally if it is removing the dependency. But, you are saying "can't delete this library".

Comment: I am using "pod 'GoogleTagManager', '~> 5.0'" to install Google tag manager. There is no "pod GoogleAnalytics" line in my Podfile.

Answer (score 0):

`GoogleTagManager` has the following dependencies.

1. `GoogleAnalytics`
2. `FirebaseAnalytics`
3. `GoogleUtilities`

If you have any one of these libraries already included in your `PodFile`, then you can remove these if they are the cause of any compiler errors.

The link is for creating your own `PodSpec`. I believe that we can't really exclude dependencies from some other library's pod.